# Backbone collection.reset function returns array

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following code in backbone view:

```
getAccounts: function() {
    var filteredCollection = this.view.collection.reset(this.view.collection.where({ AccountStatus: 'Open' }));

    return filteredCollection;
}
```

And I assume that this code returns me collection according to doc link http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset

But it returns an array. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says

> Returns the newly-set models

This means you get an array containing newly set models. It doesn't say it returns the collection itself. There is no reason to return the collection itself because you just performed this action on the collection and you already have access to it.

You can just do `return this.view.collection` instead.